# Custom connector for connecting 8-pin to 20-pin

Tags: pcb, connector, jtag, socket, interconnect

ARM-based device have 8-pin 2x4pin JTAG header. J-Link debug probe have standard 20-pin J-Link connector. I have 8-pin 2x4 Socket-Socket IDC Ribbon Cable.
[image]

One end connects to the 8-pin JTAG header on device, and the other end should be connected to J-Link probe. What is better way to interface this 2x4 pin socket with 20-pin J-Link probe? Should be used a custom-built connector for this, which connects matching pins? Please advice the most handy way.

Comment: I just make up little PCBs that convert from 20 pin to 10 pin connecting the relevant pins and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This wasn't too hard too find. I am sure there are more.

searched ... 20-pin J-Link connector 8-pin 2x4

This adapter is designed to allow standard 20-pin ARM JTAG devices to connect to the FDI 10-pin mini-JTAG on µEZGUI units and ARM based SOMDIMM units.

[image]

with 100k Pullup to SWDIO and 100k Pulldown to SWCLK

Comment: True, but trick is that pinout placement on custom header (8-pin in my case) will not match (and not obliged) the standard 20-pin J-Link connector, as no standards on pin positions, every manufacturer use own pin placement. So without custom converter board this can't be solved.

Comment: So make your own board up in that stylee.

Comment: Or 20-pin version of this fly wire [cable](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0245/8645/products/DSC_0204_1024x1024.jpg?v=1497130730).

Comment: Note that in the 20 wire cable, at least every second one is GND. For high-speed JTAG, you need to take crosstalk into account when designing such an adapter.

Comment: I am sure you could mate 10x2 Male header to a Female 4x2   socket  and connect with short resistor wire leads but it might look like a centipede mating with a spider.

Comment: at 50 MHz the inductance of 1cm connection will not be too bad if not a 120 ohm impedance, otherwise wrap ground around signal connections, or make a controlled impedance board.

Comment: @Simon Richter then probably possible to use 2.54mm 20-Pin crimp connector housing on one side with 8 wires attached, that mates JTAG header (another sort of fly wire cable).

Comment: you dont want fly wires, you want <1cm short paths with mechanical and electrical solid connections